# R text mining - how to identify word that precedes the keyword

Tags: r, text, count, frequency, text-mining

I am working on text mining using R, I would like to identify if some words precede my focal keyword by three or fewer words. For instance, my focal keyword is  **compatibility** and I wanted to know if the word **limited** precedes my keyword by three or fewer words. Thus, I wanted to get frequency count in a text regarding how many times the following combination appears (X=any other word):

- limited compatibility
- limited X compatibility
- limited X X
  compatibility

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using tidytext to find skip ngrams:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

x <- 'I am working on text mining using R, I would like to identify if some words precede my focal keyword by three or fewer words. For instance, my focal keyword is compatibility and I wanted to know if the word limited precedes my keyword by three or fewer words. Thus, I wanted to get frequency count in a text regarding how many times the following combination appears (X=any other word):

limited compatibility
limited X compatibility
limited X X compatibility

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.'

data_frame(x) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(line, x, 'lines') %>% 
    mutate(line_number = row_number()) %>%
    unnest_tokens(ngram, line, 'skip_ngrams', n = 2, k = 2) %>% 
    filter(grepl('limited', ngram), grepl('compatibility', ngram)) 
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   line_number                 ngram
#>         <int>                 <chr>
#> 1           2 limited compatibility
#> 2           3 limited compatibility
#> 3           4 limited compatibility
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with base R and regular expressions.
`grepRaw` provides the position of each matched regex pattern (with argument `all = TRUE`). The length of this result provides the number of matches.

```
d <- c("
Limited compatibility Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla maximus lobortis 
tellus quis egestas. Donec non dignissim urna. Praesent at commodo ligula. 
Cras laoreet limited compatibility interdum mi nec euismod. Ut interdum odio non sem luctus iaculis. Mauris id sapien limited X XXXX compatibility accumsan, imperdiet justo non,limited compatibility egestas felis. Morbi commodo lectus limited X compatibility scelerisque limited XXX compatibility est bibendum, vel varius tellus vulputate. Aenean dictum accumsan limited X compatibility neque limited X X compatibility sed dictum. Vivamus finibus lacus sit amet iaculis molestie. Fusce enim limited X compatibility sapien, iaculis quis leo non, pellentesque lobortis arcu. Proin commodo limited X XXX XXXXX compatibility velit placerat venenatis mattis. Limited compatibility Curabitur et laoreet ipsum. Limited compatibility
")

> length(grepRaw("Limited compatibility", d, ignore.case = TRUE, all = TRUE))
[1] 5
> length(grepRaw("limited \\w+ compatibility", d, ignore.case = TRUE, all = TRUE))
[1] 4
> length(grepRaw("limited (\\w+ ){2}compatibility", d, ignore.case = TRUE, all = TRUE))
[1] 2
> length(grepRaw("limited (\\w+ ){3}compatibility", d, ignore.case = TRUE, all = TRUE))
[1] 1
```

The following regex matches "limited X compatibility neque limited X X compatibility" and this is not the entended behavior

```
> length(grepRaw("limited (\\w+ ){6}compatibility", d, ignore.case = TRUE, all = TRUE))
[1] 1
```

Maybe safer then to place every "Limited xx compatibility" pattern on a single line :

```
d <- gsub("Limited", "\nLimited", d, ignore.case = TRUE)
d <- gsub("compatibility", "compatibility\n", d, ignore.case = TRUE)
# writeLines(d)
```

This is now correct

```
> length(grepRaw("limited (\\w+ ){6}compatibility", d, ignore.case = TRUE, all = TRUE))
[1] 0
```